# Parsing a CSV file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

My goal is to parse this CSV data:

```
Time,Tank,Product,Volume,TC Vol,Ullage,90 Ul,Height,Water,Temp
2017-10-19T18:52:41.118408,1,UNLEADED,4406,4393,7221,6058.3,37.49,0,64.15
2017-10-19T18:52:41.118408,3,SUPER,8317,8278,3310,2147.3,61.4,0,66.74
2017-10-19T18:52:41.118408,4,ADSL2,6807,6774,4820,3657.3,51.98,0,70.46
2017-10-19T18:53:13.894066,1,UNLEADED,4406,4393,7221,6058.3,37.49,0,64.15
2017-10-19T18:53:13.894066,3,SUPER,8313,8273,3314,2151.3,61.37,0,66.74
2017-10-19T18:53:13.894066,4,ADSL2,6805,6772,4822,3659.3,51.97,0,70.46
```

Given the a list of Tank numbers, a primary key, and a data column:

```
>>>tank_numbers = [1, 3]
>>>primary_key = 'Time'
>>>data_column = 'Volume'
>>>
>>>parse_csv('csv_file.csv', tank_numbers, primary_key, data_column)

[
  {'Time': '2017-10-19T18:52:41.118408', 'UNLEADED': '4406', 'SUPER': '8317'}
  {'Time': '2017-10-19T18:53:13.894066', 'UNLEADED': '4406', 'SUPER': '8317'}
]
```

I have a few questions about the following code;

1. Using only the standard library, is there a more simple way?
   What I have seems like too much just to get the needed information.
2. Should I be breaking up the `parse_csv` function into smaller pieces similar
   to `_parse_csv_to_dicts` and `_get_tank_names`.

```
import csv

def _parse_csv_to_dicts(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        return list(csv.DictReader(f))

def _get_tank_names(tanks=None, data=None):
    names = list()
    for n in tanks:
        for tank_dict in data:
            if tank_dict['Tank'] == str(n):
                names.append(tank_dict['Product'])
                break
    return names

def parse_csv(file, tanks, primary_key, data_key):
    """
    :param file: The raw csv data file
    :param tanks: A list of tank numbers, as labeled in the raw csv
    :param key: a list of the keys needed from the raw csv
    :return: a list of dictionaries
    """
    d1 = _parse_csv_to_dicts(file)

    # Remove unneeded tanks from data
    d2 = [row for row in d1 if int(row['Tank']) in tanks]

    # Remove unneeded keys from rows
    keys = [primary_key, data_key, 'Product']
    d3 = [{key:row[key] for key in keys} for row in d2]

    # Create new row template
    tank_names = _get_tank_names(tanks=tanks, data=d1)
    row_template = {key:None for key in (tank_names + [primary_key])}

    # New rows from row template
    d4 = []
    for row in d3:
        # update new row with available keys
        new_row = {key:row.get(key) for key in row_template}

        # update new row with matching values
        for key in new_row:
            if key in row.values():
                new_row[key] = row[data_key]

        # remove keys with None value
        new_row = {k:v for k,v in new_row.items() if v is not None}
        d4.append(new_row)

    # Merge all rows based on Time key
    merged = {}
    for row in d4:
        if row[primary_key] in merged:
            merged[row[primary_key]].update(row)
        else:
            merged[row[primary_key]] = row

    return [value for value in merged.values()]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general I think this code looks excellent.  You have made good use of comprehensions.  I have two suggestions:

#### More Comprehensions:

This:

```
def _get_tank_names(tanks=None, data=None):
    names = list()
    for n in tanks:
        for tank_dict in data:
            if tank_dict['Tank'] == str(n):
                names.append(tank_dict['Product'])
                break
return names
```

Can be expressed as:

```
def _get_tank_names(tanks=None, data=None):
    tanks = {str(n) for n in tanks}
    return {t['Product'] for t in data if t['Tank'] in tanks}
```

This converts `tanks` to a `set` while performing the `str()` conversion, to clean things up a bit.  Then the result can be generated in a single statement.

#### Gathering like elements

So this entire section:

```
# Create new row template
tank_names = _get_tank_names(tanks=tanks, data=d1)
row_template = {key: None for key in (tank_names + [primary_key])}

# New rows from row template
d4 = []
for row in d3:
    # update new row with available keys
    new_row = {key: row.get(key) for key in row_template}

    # update new row with matching values
    for key in new_row:
        if key in row.values():
            new_row[key] = row[data_key]

    # remove keys with None value
    new_row = {k: v for k, v in new_row.items() if v is not None}
    d4.append(new_row)

# Merge all rows based on Time key
merged = {}
for row in d4:
    if row[primary_key] in merged:
        merged[row[primary_key]].update(row)
    else:
        merged[row[primary_key]] = row

return [value for value in merged.values()]
```

Can be reduced down to:

```
merged = {}
for row in d3:
    merged.setdefault(row['Time'], {'Time': row['Time']}) \
        [row['Product']] = row['Volume']

return [v for k, v in sorted(merged.items())]
```

The cornerstone here is using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to accumulate the records that match the timestamp.

#### So how does the setdefault work?

We create an empty dict, the keys to which will be the timestamps we will be accumulating data for.

```
merged = {}
```

Loop through the data, a row at a time:

```
for row in d3:
```

Look up the element in our dict corresponding to the timestamp for this row:

```
merged.setdefault(row['Time'], {})
```

This is most of the magic, it will populate `merged[this rows timestamp]` with an empty dict if one is not already there, and then return the dict, so that we can put something in it.  An empty `dict` would often be sufficient, but in this case you also need the timestamp in the final dict, so we can extend the statement to be:

```
merged.setdefault(row['Time'], {'Time': row['Time']})
```

This will return a dict with the timestamp already populated, the first time we see that timestamp.  In subsequent loops when we see the timestamp, it will return the dict that was built the previous time we saw the timestamp.

To finish the dict creation code we set the `Product` and `Volume` data into the dict with:

```
merged.setdefault(row['Time'], {'Time': row['Time']}) \
    [row['Product']] = row['Volume']
```

Lastly, return the list of dicts we built, sorted by the timestamp with:

```
return [v for k, v in sorted(merged.items())]
```

Ain't Python fun? :-)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your edit explaining what you were doing with the setdefault method. Definitely a useful tool. Thank you for your time! Yes, it sure is fun!